# Can't search for indirectly locked posts

Tags: bug, search, locked-posts, historical-lock

For context, I'm trying to hunt down all locked posts linking to imageshack.

A search with [an unspecified lock status](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3aimageshack.us%20%20is%3aa&searchOn=3), sorted by votes for a higher hit rate, yields these two high on the list:

> [image: Screenshot showing two locked posts when searching for url:imageshack.us]

These are https://stackoverflow.com/a/423178/6296561 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/215911/6296561, both of which are provably locked (and not deleted, at the time of writing).

However, there are more than just these two, but I'm using these two for the sake of demonstration for my next search; `url:imageshack.us locked:yes`. This search previously yielded three posts that I've dealt with. I've yet to touch the two demonstration answers, however.

My personal expectation here is to have at least two results. It's trivial to prove there are at least two locked answers with an imageshack URL, re: the example from two paragraphs ago. To my surprise, [there are none](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aimageshack.us+locked%3Ayes&searchOn=3).

I assume this is because the answers themselves aren't *technically* locked; the *question* is locked, and it's locked in a way that drags the answer with it. Yet, in every interaction regard, the answer is still locked. Essentially, it's indirectly locked, but locked regardless. Whether it's locked indirectly or directly, it's still locked, and interactions are blocked. Consequently, I believe it should show up when I search only locked posts.

Obligatory note that this is probably an edge-case with historical locks specifically; I haven't found other questions with a different type of lock exhibiting this behavior, though I haven't specifically attempted to do so either.

Comment: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1617419/list-of-locked-answers-with-imageshack-urls)?

Comment: That's a workaround, but it's an annoying one. Search should work here; it's not like it's a massively complex query